# importing method that creates new objects

Tags: python

I am a bit confused with importing methods when they include creating new objects. It's hard for me to explain because as I am still learning the language but here is an example of what is going on.

I have a `macrocalc.py`

```
from interface import Interface

def main():
    a = Interface();
    print "Welcome!"
    print "!hat would you like to do?"
    a.display_options()

if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Later on in my code, I import main with `from marcocalc import main`. Then I run the `main()` method. But I get the error:

```
  File "macrocalc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from interface import Interface
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/interface.py", line 1, in <module>
    from addFood import addfood
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/addFood.py", line 2, in <module>
    from macrocalc import main
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/macrocalc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from interface import Interface
ImportError: cannot import name Interface
```

my `interface.py`:

```
from addFood import addfood

class Interface:
    #options = ["1 - create a meal plan","2 - add food","3 - look up food"]

    def display_options(self):
        options = ["1 - create a meal plan","2 - add food","3 - look up food"]
        for choice in options:
            print choice

        selection = int(raw_input())
        if selection > 3:
            print "Incorrect selection. Please try again."
            self.display_options()
        else: 
            print "You chose: ",
            if selection == 1:
                print "\'create a meal plan\'"

            elif selection == 2:
                print "\"add food\""
                addfood()

            else: 
                print "\"look up food\""
```

I tried adding the line `from interface import Interface` but the error still persists.

If more of the code is required. I will add it to the post. Please let me know

Comment: How is the file system? (hint, use '$ tree' command on the root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have introduced the dreaded **circular dependency**.

In `macrocalc.py`, on line 1:

```
# Call this A
from interface import Interface
```

In `interface.py`, on line 1:

```
from addFood import addfood
```

In `addFood.py`, on line 2:

```
from macrocalc import main
```

But now we are back to A!

You have to refactor your program so it doesn't do this. :)

Comment: how would u suggest I fix this?

Comment: Well my general advice stands: refactor. Specifically it's hard to comment without being more familiar with your code. At a glance, seeing only what I can see, I might merge `interface.py` into `macrocalc.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You've created an import loop:

```
File "macrocalc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from interface import Interface
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/interface.py", line 1, in <module>
    from addFood import addfood
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/addFood.py", line 2, in <module>
    from macrocalc import main
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/macrocalc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from interface import Interface
ImportError: cannot import name Interface
```

Look at what would happen if there was no error, and the code ran exactly as you had written it:

1. interface imports addFood
2. addFood imports macrocalc
3. macrocalc imports interface
4. interface imports addFood
5. addFood imports macrocalc
6. macrocalc imports interface

...

You need to remove an import statement somewhere to prevent an infinite loop of imports.

Comment: You should probably refactor your code, too. Just removing an import statement should probably only break stuff. Otherwise, why did you have it there in the first place?

Comment: Yes, why did you feel that all of these files depended on one another?

Comment: Generally, the `main`, or `__init__` file is the one that imports all of the others and mixes them together. Others shouldn't really depend on `main`